# Grails JSON rendering

Tags: json, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I use Grails 2.3.8. I'm noticing strange behavior in Grails JSON rendering. I have a domain class `ShiftUpdateResponse` mapped to mongodb that looks as below.

```
     class ShiftUpdateResponse {
        List<Employee> employees
        SalesPersonHours salesPersonHours;
        Integer fromDate
        Integer toDate
        Integer success

        static mapWith = "mongo"
        static hasMany = [employees:Employee]
        static embedded = ['employees','salesPersonHours']
        static constraints = {
           salesPersonHours nullable:true
           success nullable:true 
           fromDate nullable:true 
           toDate nullable:true 
        }

        String toString() {
           " $employees"
        }
      }
```

When I create a `ShiftUpdateResponse` object in my controller and render it as JSON using the snippet below:

```
   def  sur = new ShiftUpdateResponse(employees:[], salesPersonHours:[], success:1, fromDate:from, toDate:to)
   println "from " + from
   println "to " + to
   println "from sur " + sur.fromDate
   println "to sur " + sur.toDate
   JSON.use('deep')
   render sur as JSON
```

I notice the following things

- when I do not save the created instance `sur` before rendering, the console output is

  ```
  from 20130624
  to 20130623
  from sur null
  to sur null
  ```
- when I do save the created instance before rendering, the console output is

  ```
  from 20130624
  to 20130623
  from sur null
  to sur 20130623
  ```

In either case, the JSON rendered does not contain the fields `fromDate` and `toDate` . What could be the reason ? (I do not need this instance to be persisted, I just need it to be rendered as a JSON).

EDIT:

The JSON rendered looks like :

```
    {
"class": "com.scheduling.json.week.graphicalMode.ShiftUpdateResponse",
"id": 37,
"employees": [],
"salesPersonHours": null,
"success": 1
    }
```

Controller code :

```
    @Transactional
    def updateShift(){

    def reqJson = request.JSON
    somService.updateShift(reqJson)


    def from
    def to
    def week = WeekJson.get(reqJson.week_id)

    // code to construct from and to from week

    def sur = new ShiftUpdateResponse(employees:[],salesPersonHours:[],success:1,fromDate:from,toDate:to)

    //sur.save(flush:true)

    println "from "+from
    println "to "+to
    println "from sur "+sur.fromDate
    println "to sur "+sur.toDate


    JSON.use('deep')
    render sur as JSON

}
```

Comment: How about showing the rendered JSON? Show the complete controller action

Comment: @JamesKleeh I have added the JSON and the skeleton of the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry,noob mistake. The problems might have been because, there was another copy of the same file in a different package. Deleting the duplicate fixed things up.